Induced subgraphs with interface
I am interested in hypergraphs with interfaces, I'll call them simply "graphs" in the following.
Formally, a graph of sort $k$ is a tuple $(V,E,i)$ with $E\subseteq V^+$ is the set of edges, each edge is not necessarily binary, for instance $v_1v_2v_3$ links distinct vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$ in this order.
The interface $i\in V^k$ is a list of $k$ distinct vertices.
A context is a graph together with a distinguished edge $h$ called its "hole". Thus a context has both a sort, and an "arity", which is the arity of its hole.
If $C$ is a context of sort $n$ and arity $k$, and $G$ is a graph of sort $k$, we define the substitution $C[G]$ as the graph obtained by removing replacing the hole of $C$ by $G$, and identifying the vertices of the interface of $G$ with those of the hole of $C$. The interface of $C[G]$ is that of $C$.
I call "island" of a graph $G$ a subgraph $I$ such that there exists a context $C$ with $G=C[I]$. Note that it implies that $I$ is an induced subgraph, except possibly for edges between vertices of its interface.
Notice that if $I$ is an island of $G=(V,E,i)$, then vertices from $i$ can only appear in $I$ at the interface.
For instance, if $G$ is a triangle with binary edges and interface $v_1v_2v_3$ (all three vertices of $G$), then its islands of sort $2$ are all pairs of distincts vertices, but the whole $G$ is not, because the interface of $G$ cannot be "inside" an island.
I want to understand the structure of maximal islands with a fixed sort. For instance here is a conjecture: for every pair of maximal binary islands, either they are the same when forgetting interfaces, or they intersect only on their interfaces.
Do you know of any paper or reference where this concept is studied ?

Can you explain the terminology? What is a "context"? Is "interface" the same thing as an "island"?

@EmilJeřábek I added the necessary formalism, indeed it was needed.

I’m still quite lost. First, any way I look at it, any graph $G$ is an island of itself, hence in particular, the only maximal island of $G$ is $G$? Second, how is $I$ an induced subgraph of $G$? Given a graph $G$, what stops me from e.g. making $G=C[I]$ where $C$ is the same as $G$ with a hole listing all vertices, and $I$ the empty graph on the same number of vertices?

Is there any paper where these concepts are properly defined?

@EmilJeřábek I added precisions and an example showing why $G$ is not always an island of itself, for some fixed island sort. Indeed the induced subgraph property is only true for edges involving at least one inner (ie non-interface) vertex.
